# Notebook fails to import module in same folder (Python)

Tags: python, import, ipython

In my notebook analysis I want to use a few functions that are written in a different script (but in the same folder). It looks like this:

```
main folder:
     - subfolder
         - __init__.py
         - my_script.py
         - my_notebook.ipynb
```

When I want to import `my_script` in a cell in `my_notebook` I consistently get a `No module named my_script` error. I don't understand why this happens even though the files are in the same folder. How am I supposed to import `my_script` ? No error is thrown by the IDE and I tried a variety of ways to import it without much success.

Comment: How (the actual line) and from where (current working directory) do you import? What is the traceback?

Comment: @KlausD. The actual lines I tried are `import my_script` and `from subfolder import my_script`. If I do `os.getcwd()`, I get two foldesr above the main_folder as the working directory. (The standard Pycharm folder in C:/User). The traceback is a rather simple: ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-ae58181407fb> in <module>()
----> 1 import data_prep

ImportError: No module named data_prep

Comment: The working directory is the problem here. It is usually one of the bases to import from. If it would be `main folder` `import subfolder` and `from subfolder import my_script` would work. Can you run the script from `main folder`?

Comment: @KlausD. I tried your suggestion from a new script in `main_folder`. It works fine to do `from mainfolder import subfolder`, but when I do `from subfolder import my_script` it throws an ImportError on this line stating `No module named subfolder`

Comment: Then you are still one level to high. But then you can just use `subfolder.myscript` after the import or use `from mainfolder.subfolder import myscript`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how notebooks work, you cannot do that. As far as I know, you only import from the global PYTHONPATH in notebooks.

The simplest solution I found, and that I often use is this.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Then you should be able to do `import my_script`

Comment: This does not work for me. Am I supposed to substitute something where the period is?

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said in the comments, the problem appears the *current working directory* (cwd). One can use the following commands to find what jupyter notebooks considers the cwd, then change it *relatively* or *directly* from there:

```
import os                       #imports os
print(os.getcwd())              #check the cwd
os.chdir("new_folder")          #change the cwd via absolute or relative path
print(os.getcwd())              #check the new cwd
```

One can look at these two websites for more information: 
[note](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-os-getcwd-chdir/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20you%20can%20get,chdir()%20.) 
[python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

*Some more context:*
I encounted this problem when moving jupyter notebooks between folders in jupyter lab linux server, it may be that the cwd isn't updated when one moves the notebook. 
*This is quite an old question, but perhaps this answer will help the next person with this problem*

Comment: You can use `pwd` in a cell in Jupyter to print the current working directory. (I think that assumes that automagic is on, which it generally is by default.) To change directory in Jupyter/IPython you can more conveniently use `%cd`, see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) for more about that. It is good to know the pure Python versions, too; however, in this case the Jupyter convenience commands are handy for the described situation.